# How to get frame's current src using chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, href, frame, src

I have a webpage which contains 2 frames:top and main.
main frame is not under my domain, and it could be any websites.

Yes I can get $("#main").attr("src") but it could only reach the "first" src, not the "current" src.

And I know it's not possible to be done by javascript due to the security issue, so I am thinking creating a chrome extension to do it.

I tried with Content Script, but I think it can not do it because it's just add js to the page.

Is there anyone who could offer some advices? Thx

Answer (score 1):

I can answer this part:

> I tried with Content Script, but I think it can not do it because it's just add js to the page.

You just need to set `"all_frames": true` in the manifest:

```
"content_scripts": [ {
    "js": [ "script.js" ],
    "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*" ],
    "all_frames": true
} ],
```

this will inject scripts to each frame as well.

Comment: Thx I tried that, it does add js into frame but how do I determine whether it's exactly the frame I want? cuz it will add scripts into all the pages and frames of my chrome.

Comment: Inside the content_script you can access document.documentURI.  However, I don't know how to distinguish between 2 iframes if they happen to have the same source...